# Every runtime error reported as SIGSEGV error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have linked some c++ codes to android studio project and it works with no problem, but every time I encounter with a runtime error in java code, android studio won't tell me the problem precisely and reports only this error in debugger:

```
Signal = SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xc))
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This primarily occurs due to one of the 2 reasons : 
1) Invalid memory reference.

2) Eating up too much memory.

Now, debugging this issue can be a bit intimidating.
So start finding out points where your code may be doing INVALID MEMORY ACCESS causing SIGSEGV error or points where your code is starting too many threads.

And You have to find out if this issue is regularly occuring or 1 in 5(or so) times.

Because I encountered the problem in one project and that occured 1 in 5-6 times.